MPI one sided communication
Requesting more sets of eyes to look over an implementation for school project.  This particular function is failing the correctness test (everything else passes ok).  I think the logic for start and end for each rank may be to blame but not sure. The beginning and rebalanced arrays are checksumd for equality and that is where it fails meaning there is probably overlap or corruption.
void rebalance(const dist_sort_t *data, const dist_sort_size_t myDataCount, dist_sort_t **rebalancedData, dist_sort_size_t *rCount) {

    // Get number of processes
    int nProcs;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nProcs);

    // Get rank of the process
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    dist_sort_size_t global_N;
    // Perform MPI all reduce to sum up all local_N's and get global_N
    MPI_Allreduce(&myDataCount, &global_N, 1, MPI_TYPE_DIST_SORT_SIZE_T, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    uint64_t dataPerProc, limit;
    // Datacount per process
    dataPerProc = global_N / nProcs;

    // no of processes with extra data
    limit = global_N % nProcs;

    //Additional debugging specifically for handling of limit > 0
     if (limit > 0)
     {
        std::cout << "Handling extra data - Rank: " << rank << ", Extra Data Limit: " << limit << std::endl;
     }

    // assign datasize for curr process  //gives the first few ranks the extras
    dist_sort_size_t myCount = dataPerProc + (rank < limit ? 1 : 0);
    std::cout<< "myCount: " << myCount << std::endl;

    // allocate array for output
    dist_sort_t *balanced = (dist_sort_t *)malloc(myCount * sizeof(dist_sort_t));
    int balanced_size = myCount * sizeof(dist_sort_t);
    std::cout<< "balanced_size: " << balanced_size << std::endl;

    // Global starting and ending index of this rank
    uint64_t myStartGlobal, myEnd;
    MPI_Exscan(&myDataCount, &myStartGlobal, 1, MPI_TYPE_DIST_SORT_SIZE_T, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (rank == 0) {
        myStartGlobal = 0;
    }
    myEnd = myStartGlobal + myDataCount -1;

    MPI_Win win;
    // create window for one-way communication
    MPI_Win_create(balanced, myCount * sizeof(dist_sort_t), sizeof(dist_sort_t), MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &win);

    MPI_Win_fence(MPI_MODE_NOPRECEDE, win);

    uint64_t next = myStartGlobal;


       while (next <= myEnd)
       {
               uint64_t dest;
                if (next < global_N) 
                {
                    dest = next / dataPerProc;  // Calculate which process should receive the 'next' data item
                }
            else
            {
                dest = nProcs - 1;  // Assign to the last process if 'next' is outside the range of available data items
            }


        uint64_t disp = next % dataPerProc; // offset in destination rank
        uint64_t size = std::min(dataPerProc - disp, myEnd - next + 1); // size to write to destination rank

        if (dest < nProcs) 
        {
            // writing to destination rank
            MPI_Put(&data[next - myStartGlobal], size, dtype, dest, disp, size, dtype, win);
        }

        next += size;
    }
    
    MPI_Win_fence(MPI_MODE_NOSUCCEED, win);

    // assigning rebalanced data
    *rebalancedData = balanced;
    *rCount = myCount;
}

Thanks!

Please fix your indentation. I can't see what statement are in what blocks. It seems like the Fence is outside the while loop. Would it hlp if you move it inside?

When asking a question in SO, please include a minimal self contained reproducer. Also describe the discrepancy between the observed and expected result.

MPI_Put isn't atomic so any overlapping writes will be corrupted.  Please use MPI_Accumulate(..,op=MPI_REPLACE,..) to realize any atomic write operation.
If this doesn't fix the problem, update the question with more information.
